# Error in class file: "Identifier expected"

Tags: java, arrays, class

Here is my current code of the class file i am using for my project, Im getting two identifier expected errors on the lines with  public double highStoreSales(store)      and public double averageStoreSales(quarter)

What am i missing?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SalesAnaylzer //extends SalesManager
{

    DecimalFormat pricePattern = new DecimalFormat("$#0.00");
    int[][] sales = new int[3][4];


    public SalesAnaylzer(String fileName) throws IOException {

        File inputFile = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
                sales[row][col] = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String data = "";
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            data = data + "\nStore " + (row + 1) + ": ";
            for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
                data = data + "QTR " + (col + 1) + ": " + pricePattern.format(sales[row][col]) + " ";
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    public double totalSales() {
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
                total = total + sales[row][col];
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public double highStoreSales(store) {
        double highest = 0.0;
        for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            if (sales[row][store] > highest)
                highest = sales[row][store];
        }
        return pricePattern.format(highest);
    }

    public double averageStoreSales(quarter) {
        double total = 0.0;
        double avg = 0.0;
        for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
            total = total + sales[quarter][col];
        }
        avg = (total / 4);
        return pricePattern.format(avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Format your code with consistent, reasonable indentation. *Edit*: I've done it for you on this occasion.

Comment: also did i import to much?

Comment: @ user: Questions should be *specific* (as your original one was), and individual. Posting follow-on questions about other things isn't the way SO works. If you have another question, post it separately, with all the necessary context.

Comment: yea i've done that before and people complained...

Comment: @ user: No one should complain about *distinct* questions being asked *distinctly*. That's perfectly fine and correct. If they complain, too bad for them. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You have argument names without types, e.g.:

```
public double averageStoreSales(quarter)
```

You need to say what type `quarter` is, e.g.:

```
public double averageStoreSales(int quarter)
// -----------------------------^
```

Comment: That got rid of the identifier error but it created an incompatible types error with the decimal format

Comment: @user2985542: You have to use the appropriate type for what you're doing. I used `int` for `quarter` because you use it as an index into the `sales` array. I'm sure there are other, unrelated, issues, you'll just have to work through them in the normal way.

Comment: thats what i thought so i used double for quarter and store and it gave me loss of precision error because of the array

Comment: @user2985542: Array indexes are always `int` in Java.

Comment: right which is why im stuck because if i put int for quarter why do i get an error for highest when i already declared it a double? "Error: incompatible types
  required: double"

Comment: @user2985542: Because you've declared `sales` as `int[][]`. Not a `double` in sight. So `sales[quarter][col]` is an `int`, not a `double`. But this is all off-topic. The problem you asked about is caused by not having a type on your arguments.

Comment: i know its off topic but fixing one error caused another.